# Pitch detection on array of floating point numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio-recording, pitch-tracking

I'm doing voice recording in javascript, and storing the recording as an array of signed floats. What would I need to determine (and ultimately, adjust) pitch on the array? I've seen various algorithms for C++, but they don't seem to be very helpful in my situation. I even downloaded and tried this one to see if I could convert parts of it to javascript:

http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

But all that actually did was make the recording louder, regardless of the settings I chose.

Comment: Have you looked at the PitchShifter.cs file? http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#VoiceRecorder.Audio/PitchShifter.cs

Comment: I looked at it, but in practice, it doesn't work. I checked the console, and it detected all of the samples at 0mhz. There's no way my voice is that low. Being that that's the case, I really don't think I should be porting non-working software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to try to provide an exhaustive answer here, but rather describe my own findings discovered on my journey of wrestling with similar issues in audio programming.

### Pitch Detection

If you're sound is monophonic (as it sounds that is is based on your comment to jeff), I've implemented pitch **detection** using auto-correlation techniques, mostly because it's relatively simple compared to other pitch detection algorithms.

The idea, if you're unfamiliar, is as follows:

1. Slide a sample over itself (with a predetermined window size; in 1-sample increments)
2. At each step, calculate the absolute difference between the original wave and the slid window (hard to explain verbally).

   - as you slide the window, keep a record of the score calculated in (2)
   - when the wave correlates with itself, the score will hit a minimum, and the time-location of this minimum specifies the signals periodicity.

In my implementation, this was the only algorithm that worked well (when fed samples of my voice; I didn't try a variety of samples however).

That was a crude explanation of how autocorrelation works, and this article provides a very nice comparison of different pitch-detection algorithms:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~pdelac/154/m154paper.htm

### Pitch Shifting

Of course, you could get really cheap pitch shifting by just resampling, but that sounds similar to a record being played too fast, which is not acceptable in many circumstances.

As far as pitch **shifting** goes, I haven't gotten that far yet in my implementation, but last I left off, I was looking at phase vocoders as a possible solution.  What's hard is finding a decent explanation of how these algorithms work that provides some intuition on the reason why they work the way they do instead of just providing soley abstract mathmatical equations.